# Keycloak login returns 404 using JavaScript adapter

Tags: javascript, html, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak's bower package to create a very basic demo HTML/JS app. I have Keycloak running locally and `keycloak.init()` seems to work (no error triggered). However when I call `keycloak.login()` a 404 is returned. Might the login URL be wrongly created by the adapter?

The URL returned by `keycloak.createLoginUrl()` is

```
https://<keycloak url>/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=account&redirect_uri=file%3A%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fjgallaso%2FProjects%2Fdemos%2Fkeycloak-simple-web-client%2Findex.html&state=b167dc0b-3e5b-4c67-87f7-fd5289fb7b8f&nonce=1e2cb386-51db-496a-8943-efcf4ef5d5e1&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid
```

And this is my entire code:

```
<head>
  <script src="bower_components/keycloak/dist/keycloak.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="login">Login</button>
</body>

<script>
  var keycloak = Keycloak({
    url: 'https://keycloak-keycloak.192.168.37.1.nip.io',
    realm: 'demo',
    clientId: 'account'
  });

  keycloak.init()
    .success(authenticated => {
      document.getElementById("login")
              .addEventListener("click", () => { keycloak.login(); });

    }).error(err => {
      console.log("init, error: " + err);
    });
</script>
</head>
```

Response is a plain:

```
ERROR 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 posibilities :

1. invoque login automatically in init method
2. login manually after call init without params

1)

```
<head>
  <script src="bower_components/keycloak/dist/keycloak.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="login">Login</button>
</body>

<script>
  var keycloak = Keycloak({
    url: 'https://keycloak-keycloak.192.168.37.1.nip.io',
    realm: 'demo',
    clientId: 'account'
  });

  keycloak.init('login-required')
    .success(function(authenticated) => {


    }).error(err => {
      console.log("init, error: " + err);
    });
</script>
</head>
```

2)

```
     keycloak.init().success(function(authenticated) {

         if(authenticated == true){
            alert('usuario logeado');    
         }else{
            alert('usuario no logeado');    
            keycloak.login();

         }
        }).error(function() {
         alert('failed to initialize');

    });
```

I had trouble trying directly from the management.
file://c:/example.html
To do a better test you should leave your index.html on a local test server.
What I did was install the web server plugin for chrome and it worked for me.
I hope it'll help you.

regards